# How should I make grafana aware of telegraf and influxdb installed on different host?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf

I installed influxdb and telegraf, was configuring input.exec plugin configuration just recalled that grafana is actually installed on a different host . I am a newbie into grafana and would greatly appreciate your inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the IP address of the host machine on which influxdb is installed.

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/influxdb/

Comment: I installed influxdb , but I do not know the username an password, and as if those are the same credentials used by telegraf's db as well?!

Comment: what database to select the link you shared does not talks about infulx details.

Comment: You can use the same credential that telegraf is using provided the telegraf user has READ or ALL privileges.